# Multiple System.Web.Extensions assembly in same project?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I'm having trouble moving a website from one server to another. It seems to be a problem loading multiple versions of System.Web.Extensions. The code uses version 3.5 in most places but a third party control appears to be needing version 1.0.6. I didn't think this was possible but it appears to be working in it's current situation.

Is there a way I can use the GAC version of System.Web.Extensions for the site but import a dll of version 1.0.6 just for these controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting an assemblyBinding tag in your config like so:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```